# Integrate WordPress with PayPal IPN

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am integrating some custom pages into WordPress. These pages are link to another external application using APIs.
I have this section that links to PayPal, and upon receiving POST data from PayPal will run a file.

basically this is my file structure :-

```
wp-content/themes/myTheme/ipn
wp-content/themes/myTheme/ipn/ipnconfig.php
wp-content/themes/myTheme/ipn/ipn.php
```

After successful payment, I need to call ipn.php 
Thus my $notify_url is "ipn/ipn.php" or should it be "ipn.php" ? I tried several other methods like putting in full path, use dirname , etc but it seems that the file is not being called.

Anyone tried something similar before? How do you handle the post back URL ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not put these IPN files in the root of your site? They shouldn't need Wordpress to run

Comment: Easy tutorial to integrate IPN with your WordPress site. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/paypal-ipn-listener-wordpress-without-using-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Before using IPN you should enable it from paypal/paypal-sandbox

go to profile-> my selling tools-> Instant payment notifications -> click on update-> turn it on

also type the notification URL (your callback-listener url, ipn.php).

then in your ipn.php file catch the callback from paypal.

```
$ipn_post_data = $_POST;
if(array_key_exists('test_ipn', $ipn_post_data) && 1 === (int) $ipn_post_data['test_ipn'])
    $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
else
    $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

// Set up request to PayPal
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
));

// Execute request and get response and status code
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close connection
curl_close($request);

if($status == 200 && $response == 'VERIFIED')
{
    // All good! Proceed...
}
else
{
    // Not good. Ignore, or log for investigation...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I'm not using WordPress, the IPN is called successfully. It's just that after I integrate into WordPress then the file is not being called

Comment: never tried it before but you can try install the paypal ipn plugin for wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/

Comment: Yes, if working with WordPress I highly recommend the plugin that @Elad mentioned.